# Getting the size of a single String in a array of string in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a Array of strings and I want to get the number of characters in the particular element in the array of strings,how i can do that?
like a array arr have = {"abc", "bgfgh", "gtddsffg"}
if i use

a.length; I will get the 3 which is the no.of elements in array

but I want a method which when I apply on each element like

```
    for(int = 0;   ; i++)
    {
        int t = a[i].length; //this method doesn't work
    }
```

to return the number of characters in each element
which is the given example has to be 3,5 and 8

PLEASE REPLY?

Comment: You should understand the basics of Java first.. Please do a google search..

Comment: Use `length()` instead of `length`

Comment: yeah,ok don't go into the details as much i just want a way to count the no.of characters of a string in a string array.

Comment: @gexicide Arrays don't have `length()` as I recall, so that is not the problem here, although Strings do.

Comment: please understand it is not suppose to be looking at the syntax here,please try to understand the problem.

Comment: @user3771185, by your description it is the syntax that's causing the problem. `someString.length` won't work because Strings don't have the attribute (see my answer below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
package stackoverflow.q_24933319;

public class FindLength {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = {"abc","bgfgh","gtddsffg"};
        System.out.println("Array size is: " + arr.length);
        for(String s : arr) {
            System.out.println("Value is " + s + ", length is " + s.length());
        }
    }
}

//Output:
//Array size is: 3
//Value is abc, length is 3
//Value is bgfgh, length is 5
//Value is gtddsffg, length is 8
```

Comment: @user3771185, you can only mark one answer at a time so if you found Nikhil's answer the best you should mark that one.

Comment: yaar hud hai,i just like everybody's ans can i just mark everybody's ans.

Comment: Unfortunately not, you can only accept one of them. :)

Comment: well i'll just mark this response as u have a greater repo :p Kviiri :) though ur response sure worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Unlike arrays, `String` doesn't have an attribute `length`, but it has a method `length()` which returns the String's length (in Unicode code units, see [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length--)).

Try this: `a[i].length()`.

Comment: PlusOne from me also!

Answer (score 1):

I think a good idea is to put numbers of characters into another table. If you want, you can after that make some other operation on each of this number outside the for loop.

`String [] input = {"aaaa", "sdasdwdas", "sd"};
 int [] output = new int [input.length];
 for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
    output[i] = input[i].length();`

Answer (score 0):

I think this code has the answer to your question in at least one of the functions.

```
public int[] getEachLengthIndividually(String[] arr)
{
    int[] retArray = new int[arr.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        String string = arr[i];
        retArray[i] = string.length();
    }
    return retArray;
}

public int totalSize(String[] arr)
{
    int totalSize = 0;
    for(String string : arr)
    {
        totalSize += string.length();
    }
    return totalSize;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
     String[] arr = {"abc", "bgfgh", "gtddsffg"};
     int[] eachLengthIndividually = getEachLengthIndividually(arr);
     int totalLength = getTotalLength(arr);
     for(int i = 0; i < eachLengthIndividually.length; i++)
     {
         System.out.println("The string " + arr[i] + " at index " + i + " has length of " + eachLengthIndividually[i]);
     }
     System.out.println("The total length of all strings in the array is " + totalLength);
}
```